# What VBAT lines do I really need in this schematic? - Recharge battery & Check battery level

Tags: batteries, raspberry-pi

So I'm currently using the design & schematic of adafruit's Powerboost 1000c.
I've already discovered in a [previous thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389306/rpi-how-can-i-access-ide-via-usb-micro-do-i-need-vbus-later-in-my-design) about which VBUS lines I can remove but will have to find out what I need to do in order ot access an serial terminal/gui via usb micro but that's for another question.

My current question at hand is in the below schematic and board view what VBAT lines do I currently require and what do I not require?

My end priority goal to to be able to recharge the battery which I'm already able to do but whilst also minimzing the amount of vbat in the schematic (by minimize I mean what do I require to make my goals possible and what ones I don't require i.e. I can get rid of). This is because in adafruit's schematic the likes of vbus & vbat connect together and then meet together after connecting to their respective components at their desired pin out with the VBAT pin out depicted by the orange circle and the VBUS pin out depicted by the pink circle.

My 2nd goal is to be able to check the battery level so I can later alert the user in software as to the battery level descending below a specified threshold.

Whether this requires something extra to be added to the schematic I don't know or I can use that VBAT pin and just link it directly to the main computer in my case being a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3, it would be greatly appreciated if that's the case and you could point that out for me or any alternative routes I will have to take in order to reach this secondary goal.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `amount of vbat` .... it is unclear what you are quantifying

Comment: Oh let me rephrase that wording. what I'm meaning to say is when I look at the schematic that adafruit has supplied for their powerboost 1000c it seems there's alot of lines going to vbat. What I want to find out is which ones are actually what I need in my design such as:
_The battery providing power to the board, the usb micro providing power to recharge the battery and the ability to check the battery percentile level._

And what ones I don't require to make the above work.

Comment: there is only one `Vbat` in the circuit  .... you need to determine if a component requires a connection to `Vbat`

Comment: ^ Sorry that's probably a better rephrasing of it. Still lacking in that department regarding knowledge as you can clearly see. :-)

Comment: `LED1` seems to be an indicator, so it may be possible to remove the circuit associated with it

Comment: don't forget that a schematic diagram is not a wiring diagram .... the length of a line in a schematic diagram is not an indication of copper length  ......... it is still unclear what you are trying to achieve ..... are you sure that your intentions are not misguided?

Comment: @Jsotola, I don't think they are, where did you get that idea from?
Regarding the wiring diagram on the board I was merely pointing out the the VBAT pin (circled Orange) all of the copper trails from the components that require Vbat link up in that one spot.
My intentions as you mentioned is determining which components and lines from U6 actually require a connection to vbat to recharge, power and check battery level.
I know about the line length in schematic diagram is not indication to copper length else my board design would look alot like the schematic design if that were the case.

Comment: @Jsotola woops didn't mean to mention that :-D should of proof read that part.

Regarding the LED1 stuff I've already removed that in the next version as I don't require the leds.

Comment: the `Vbat` signal does not "meet" at the circled via .... that is just a connection between the two sides of the board .... there are several points on the circuit board like that .... actually the area where `C9` is printed on the board makes no sense .... there appears to be no reason to switch sides

Comment: there are 2 vbat signals that meet at the circled via, 1 comes from T1 & R31 via U5 and the other comes from C9, C6, L1, R14, R22, U6 & U5

The via is just there acting as the pin out for vbat which would be on adafruit's powerboost 1000c board.

The 2 via's via C9 is due to an airwire for GND that Eagle pointed out so I made that change to fix the airwire error.

Comment: you have some pretty goofy trace routing .... look at the red trace that wraps around the N$13 and Vbat terminals at bottom of picture ..... it wraps around and passes right next to itself ..... actually, looking at the pc board design as i write this, the whole Vbat net is really messed up

Comment: That board looks like it was done using a cheap auto-router.  Try routing it by yourself - even a beginner should be able to make a much nicer-looking board.  As you route the board, you will likely find you want to move some components around to make the routing easier/neater.

Comment: Funny thing is I didn't auto route it. I actually routed that myself. And as its my 1st time doing this sort of thing I suspected it wouldn't be all that good. Plus it was only single sided.

The 2nd version I'm going at it double sided and @PeterBennett I already move my components for neater routing although granted the section here isn't all that good.

Comment: Besides I think this is deviating more away from the actual question I'm asking. Routing just comes down to experience which I can sort that over time whilst I'm doing the 2ns version of the board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V<sub>BATT</sub> is preset in the MCP73871 by the factory.  The part number determines the value.

[image]

You should first understand the safety concerns regarding Li-ion batteries.
Read: [Battery University Safety Concerns with Li-ion](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_concerns_with_li_ion)

You should understand the basics of charging an Li-ion battery.
Read:  [Battery University Charging Lithium-ion](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)

[image]

You also need to understand the charge characteristics of the target Li-ion battery you are going to charge. This means you need the datasheet for the battery.

To alter the Adafruit Powerboost 1000 you need to FULLY understand is the [Microchip MCP73871](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002090D.pdf)  battery charger chip.

[image]

> Rather ironically your name speak truths about your answer. You
>   misunderstand the question I'm asking entirely. 1st and foremost I'm
>   not asking about stuff on the MCP73871. More exactly I'm talking about
>   stuff on the TPS61009RSAR and whether or not I need all of the
>   components it requires on vbat and I can remove some without effecting
>   functionality / performance, whether or not I need a pin out for VBAT
>   using a via and if I can just leave all the vbat connections
>   connected. I'm also asking for help on how I would be able to check
>   the battery level which would be connected via a RPI CM3
>   – Marc Brooks

My point is you do not understand how this circuit works well enough to even ask the correct question. This makes you dangerous. You have a responsibility for safety of which you are apparently completely unaware.

> I'm not asking about stuff...
>   More exactly I'm talking about stuff

Not a statement that inspires confidence you know what you are doing.  "Exactly" "Stuff" exactly my point. You should not be working on a Li-ion battery charger is you do not understand how the "stuff" works.

And no, you cannot remove the "stuff" on V<sub>bat</sub> otherwise the other "stuff" will not work.  Is that exact enough for you?

> I'm also asking for help on how I would be able to check
>   the battery level which would be connected via a RPI CM3

I do not know what "RPI CM3" is. You already have two low battery indicators. The LBO on the MCP73871 will work when the USB is disconnected.  The MCP73871does this for you.  The low battery threshold of the is set with the voltage divided feeding the LBI pin of the TPS61009 so you can set the level to one above or below the  LBO on the MCP73871.  You can determine the state of charge by monitoring both levels.   You need to understand the discharge curve of a Li-ion battery so you know where to set the low battery trigger threshold.  Or you can use Adafruit's settings and just look at the two LEDs.

---

Take a look at the Microchip Demo and Eval boards.

LINK: [Microchip Demo Board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51812b.pdf)

[image]

LINK: [Microchip Eval Board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51755a.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Rather ironically your name speak truths about your answer. You misunderstand the question I'm asking entirely.

1st and foremost I'm not asking about stuff on the MCP73871. More exactly I'm talking about stuff on the TPS61009RSAR and whether or not I need all of the components it requires on vbat and I can remove some without effecting functionality / performance, whether or not I need a pin out for VBAT using a via and if I can just leave all the vbat connections connected.

I'm also asking for help on how I would be able to check the battery level which would be connected via a RPI CM3.

Comment: Yes, my name is appropriate and you have substantiated it.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, your updated answer shines alot more on what I required to know. Particularly "Cannot remove stuff on vbat else it won't work" that's simply all I needed to know. So now I can leave that all connected and just remove the via that was acting as a pin out.

Also not currently working with Li-ion as using Lipo although I might change to Li-ion depending on battery space I have available so I will keep your reference to battery in mind.

RPI CM3 stands for raspberry pi Compute module 3 & thank you for the insight on battery level checking.

Comment: Li-po stands for  Li-ion polymer and uses the same chemistries. https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/the_li_polymer_battery_substance_or_hype

Comment: Now I think I understand why you asked about the "pinout". If you wanted to monitor the low battery signals with the Pi, then add output pins to LBO of both chips. The existing LEDs can serve as the pull-up resistance. The LEDs would not be required but if not used, there needs to be a pull-up resistor.   Geting back to using Vbat if you can use an ADC to measure the voltage at Vbat then you do not need the low battery signals.  You still (more so) would need to understand the charge and discharge curves.

Comment: Regarding Li-po didn't know that so that's useful although I do know that Li-po can be smaller in size compared to a li-ion which is usually cylindrical.

For the LBO on the MCP I should be able to simply use the 1K ohm resistor (R8 as the pull-up surely? And likewise on the TPS use the R20 1k resistor after the transistor as pull-down?

Just so I have a understanding also by output pins to LBO on both chips are you meaning I connect both signals together following their pull-up resistance from R8 & R20 and then funnel them as a single signal to the GPIO pin of choice on the Pi? --

Comment: --And regarding the TPS there is a transistor (T1) just after the LBO line so I'm assuming I would route a signal for LBO before it hits the transistors or would I place it after the transistor in the vbat section or drain?

Comment: Li-po being a Li-ion is just to know they will charge, discharge, explode, and start on fire the same as any other Li-ion.  If you do not need the LEDs then the datasheets say which resistance to use.  If you keep the LEDs (and transistor) in place, then just wire the micro's IO pins to the pin of the LBO pins.

Comment: By Micro I'm assuming you mean the compute module 3 pins?

Comment: Also Just checking the datasheets for both the TPS and MCP. I noticed their designs are slightly different to that of adafruit's I'm assuming I would be better off following what the datasheet says in terms of circuit but using the parts that adafruit uses?

Comment: No you should take the time to understand the difference and do what you think is best.  I would find the discharge trigger point for MCP and becasue TPS gives you the option to set the LBO trigger point I'd then set the TPS at a higher voltage than MCP.  This way you have two distinct points one for LBO (MCP) and battery approaching low from TPS.  Keep in mind these points are only valid when the USB is disconnected and the battery is discharging.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer

i highlighted the `Vbat` net

yellow on one side of the board and light red on the other side

there are some places where the trace switches sides for no reason (pink)

i think that you can streamline the trace routing a lot

[image]

Comment: Pink sections on the right are for vbus connections and 1 thermal resistor. They are like that because get when I was doing the routing in Eagle, it was throwing up Earnest airwire errors for the GND's and at the time this was the o my workaround I could think of whilst working single sided. In the 2nd version I've tidied it up as working on both sides for component placement